# How to set a label X number of pixels either left or right of an image c#

Tags: c#, image, label

I have a form with a image at the top located at point (0,5).  I have a label that takes on a department name and the size varies.  I want it to always be X number of pixels to the right of that image.  How might I go about doing that?  I included "left" in my question because it is just as relevant.  Below is that I currently have.

```
        //
        //deptName
        //
        this.deptName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.deptName.Text = CallTrak.dept_name;
        this.deptName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16F);
        this.deptName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(300, 5); // looking to get this adjusted
        this.deptName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.deptName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
        //
        // companylogo
        //
        this.companylogo = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        switch (CallTrak.user_id)
         {
             case "1":
                 this.companylogo.Image = global::Call_Tracker.Properties.Resources._1;
                 break;
             case "2":
                 this.companylogo.Image = global::Call_Tracker.Properties.Resources._2;
                 break;
             case "3":
                 this.companylogo.Image = global::Call_Tracker.Properties.Resources._3;
                 break;
             case "4":
                 this.companylogo.Image = global::Call_Tracker.Properties.Resources._4;
                 break;
             case "5":
                 this.companylogo.Image = global::Call_Tracker.Properties.Resources._5;
                 break;
             case "6": 
                 this.companylogo.Image = global::Call_Tracker.Properties.Resources._6;
                 break;
         }
         this.companylogo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 5);
         this.companylogo.Name = "companylogo";
         this.companylogo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 106);
         this.companylogo.TabIndex = 1;
         this.companylogo.TabStop = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's winforms, thought not sure in `global::Call_traker` things.

Do not modify `blablabla.Designer.cs` files directly.

By default label is autosized. You can set label text, then check its size, obtain size of your form (you may have to use `Client...` size/rectangle) or picturebox and do whatever you are trying to do, to example:

```
deptName.Text = "blablabla";
if(left)
    deptName.Location = new Location(companylogo.Left + left, companylogo.Top);
if(right)
    deptName.Location = new Location(companylogo.Left + companylogo.Width - right, companylogo.Top);
```

Label should be added after picturebox to be visible (use winform designer to move label on top).

---

If you was asking about *layouting* (position label after X pixels to the right from autosizable picturebox), then you have use container control: `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Great answer Sinatr.  I appreciate the feedback concerning the autosize.